# No module named 'exceptions'

Tags: python-3.6

[image]

помогите!при запуске программы выдает ошибку. Что делать?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Не уверен что то, что Вы запускаете предназначено для python3, потому что в python3 нет нужды в модуле exceptions >_>